# What is the difference between nextjs and nuxtjs?

Tags: next.js, nuxt.js

Hi I am working on a project and I came across next and nuxtjs and I was wondering what is the benefit of using either of them in a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developers describe Next.js as "A small framework for server-rendered universal JavaScript apps *". Next.js is a minimalistic framework for server-rendered React applications. On the other hand, *Nuxt** is detailed as "The Vue.js Framework". Nuxt.js presets all the configuration needed to make your development of a Vue.js application enjoyable You can use Nuxt.js for SSR, SPA, Static Generated, PWA and more..

https://medium.com/@pradeep_chauhan/difference-between-next-js-and-nuxt-js-368da7e492aa

https://stackshare.io/stackups/next-js-vs-nuxt

Comment: Why don't they just call it Vue.js instead of Nuxt.js then?

Comment: @TylerH [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org) is a web framework built on top of [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org) but managed separately. It adds features that Vue.js doesn't have, like a web server and API routes.

Comment: I spent about 4 years working with nuxt js and also in dockerized applications. It's one of the buggiest slowest frameworks I ever worked with. Nearly every dependency complains with nuxt. I'm glad I found next js. It's far superior and less issues